# Not allowing a third party IME - android

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

I'm developing an application where I do not want the keyboard in text fields to be replaced by a third party one that a user has installed. I want the system one to be always used. Alternatively, a custom one included with my app to be always used.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: "I do not want the keyboard in text fields to be replaced by a third party one that a user has installed" -- why would this be good for the user? What about users who use physical keyboards? What about users who need alternative input options due to physical disabilities?

Comment: I have thought of all these cases. The question remains - I do not want my app to use any third party IME. Is that possible or not? I'm am sure there are applications that do just that - e.g. banking apps for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control what keyboard the user uses within your app on Android, sorry.

At best, you could always make the user use your keyboard, but then you'd have to extend and customize every UI component that accepts input to show your keyboard when clicked instead.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible. I have used banking apps that use some kind of custom keyboard built within the application for example, and do not allow a third party IME to be used in most places. Could you go about explaining how that customization is possible?

Comment: @AnroidSec Simply override the ontouch in each of the input elements to prevent the system from handling it (this way the default keyboard won't come up). You can then display your own set of buttons to allow input then.